# Can a drain have an immediate slope after the drain trap?

Tags: plumbing, drain

I'm trying to install a sure-vent to vent a kitchen sink. The elbow I got is stretched more than I expected. Since it is so stretched it will give a short distance between the trap section and the slope to the ground. Is there any code or regulation to keep the section between the trap and slope to the ground with certain length?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would most likely not be up to code, as it would turn a P-trap into an S-trap, which could siphon the trap and allow sewer gases out of the drain.
You will need a longer section of pipe.

Comment: yeah, that's what I worried about. Do you know how long the horizontal section needs to be for a P trap?

Comment: The "arm" of the P-trap is the long horizontal section, and the arm needs to be at least 8 inches long. As I like to say, "The 'S' in S-traps stands for 'Siphon'"

Comment: Do you have any reference link for the 8 inch long arm? Then I will accept your answer. I actually realized that I can shift the trap to the right and keep the 8 inch that way...

Comment: It can depend on your pipe size. What is the pipe thickness? Then I'll be able to give you the calculated results. I got the 8 inches from a google search because you didn't provide the pipe diameter. I'll be able to give you an exact calculation if I get a pipe diameter.

Comment: The diameter is 2 inch pipe.

Comment: Here's the best thing I could find. You will want at least 5 feet of arm before you go down at all. The vent opening must always be above the trap. https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o I'm really not sure though. My area of interest is more in HVAC and electrical than plumbing.

Comment: OK, I will return the long elbow and get a shorter one if they have it because I couldn't find it in Lowe's. I'll try home-depot. Hold on, did you say 5 feet? Isn't that too much? lol

Comment: I found this article https://www.reddit.com/r/Plumbing/comments/6pislz/is_this_an_strap_will_it_work_i_just_installed_a/ I think it explains it. I need at least 4 inch long arm. I should be OK if I twist the trap to extend the arm. It won't siphon since I will use the sure-vent.

Comment: "You will want at _least_ 5 feet of arm before you go down at all" Will you explain how you got this? I've added the emphasis, and I think that should be "at _most_", based on my reading of the article you linked.

Comment: You should use a sanitary tee instead of the long radius Wye elbow for the vent connection..  Doing this will also make it easier to obtain the minimum  4" waste drain arm for your 2" drain pipes.